# cheerio - select multiples classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cheerio

i post my question hope that someone can help me,
i try to grab all the links which have an attribute for a bot
using cheerio i make a request to a url and it retrieve me a html page in a string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="google.fr" class="test"></a>
    <a href="yahoo.com" class="test"></a>
    <a href="amazon.fr" class="test"></a>
    <a href="linux.org" class="test"></a>
    <a href="facebook.com" class="no_select"></a>
    <a href="twitter.com" class="no_select"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

i tried things like this

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const page = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="google.fr" class="test"></a>
<a href="yahoo.com" class="test"></a>
<a href="amazon.fr" class="test"></a>
<a href="linux.org" class="test"></a>
<a href="facebook.com" class="no_select"></a>
<a href="twitter.com" class="no_select"></a>
</body>
</html>`
const $ = cheerio.load(page)
const links = $('.test').each( (index, elem) =>{
 console.log(elem);
});
console.log(links);
```

but without a great success.

I'm looking for a solution to retrieve an array which each element is the href attribute ok a link which have the test class using cheerio.

Thanks for you're help =)

Comment: i just edited the post =)

Answer (score 1):

I have now found a working solution:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const page = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="google.fr" class="test"></a>
<a href="yahoo.com" class="test"></a>
<a href="amazon.fr" class="test"></a>
<a href="linux.org" class="test"></a>
<a href="facebook.com" class="no_select"></a>
<a href="twitter.com" class="no_select"></a>
</body>
</html>`
const $ = cheerio.load(page)
const links = $('.test').each( (index, elem) =>{
    console.log(elem.attribs.href);
});
```